# Flying to Paro, Bhutan requires a special crew, what are the regulations?

Tags: landing, regulations, crew

I would like to fly from [Geneva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Airport) to [Paro, Bhutan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paro_Airport) on [Gulfstream GIV-SP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulfstream_IV). I was informed that I have to take a specialized pilot from Delhi. Can anyone guide me what are the formalities and what are the solutions?

Comment: Where are you flying from? What makes you think you need a specialised pilot?

Comment: Flying from Geneva. Contacted BCAA and that is what they informed.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Looks like only a few are authorised to fly there- see [Why is a special certification needed to land at Paro Airport?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/why-is-a-special-certification-needed-to-land-at-paro-airport)

Comment: Yes we saw that. That comment also support what BCAA informed us. BCAA also informed that we can get specialised pilot from Delhi. But did not gave the address or contact at Delhi. So I put the quary. Still someone can help in finding the Delhi address or contact.

Comment: @ChatterjeeS I suggest that you take the airline route unless that is absolutely not possible. In addition to the crew, you also have to consider whether the GIV is permitted to fly there- only a few aircraft have been operated there and the pilot should be certified in that.

Comment: You *might* get an answer here, but the charter company or aircraft operator should be able to find out. They have to actually plan and operate the flight, after all. There are specialized companies that provide logistics and local handling services all over the world for private flights, and the jet operator probably uses one of them already.

Comment: I believe "you have to take a specialized pilot from Delhi" just means that you'll need a pilot who is current for Paro for the leg from Delhi to Paro, and implies nothing about whether such pilot is available in Delhi. There might not even be a pilot current for Paro and rated for GIV at all—whoever gave you the message probably simply didn't know whether there is and where to find them.